# Forward all print jobs to one printer on CUPS server

Tags: printing, cups

Is there a way to send all print jobs sent to a CUPS server to a specific printer?

Say printer 1 is out of service, but printer 2 in the next room is working.

Can I have CUPS forward print jobs sent to printer 1 automatically to printer 2 without users having to select a different printer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like what you want:

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/cups-how-manage-multiple-printers